# Precomputing Countvectorizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

This is more of a question regarding good practices. I have a large amount of labeled text data and I am trying to train a binary classifier. I would like to optimize the hyperparameters in my pipeline, but the vectorization step takes a huge amount of time. Is it acceptable to vectorize the text in the training set **before** cross-validation, so that I am not revectorizing the same training text over and over?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\b[a-z|A-Z]{2,}\b')
vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = tokenizer.tokenize, ngram_range = (1,2))

X_train_vect = vect.fit_transform(X_train)

pipe = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfTransformer()),
                 ('norm', Normalizer()),
                 ('clf', SGDClassifier())])

skf = StratifiedKFold(y_train, n_folds = 5, shuffle = True)

params = {'vect__norm' : ['l1','l2'],
          'vect__use_idf' : [True, False],
          'clf__loss' : ['hinge', 'log', 'modified_huber'],
          'clf__alpha' : stats.expon(scale = 0.0001)}

gs = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipe,
                        param_distributions = params,
                        n_iter = 50,
                        scoring = 'accuracy',
                        verbose = 3,
                        cv = skf)

gs.fit(X_train_vect, y_train)
```

I've also tried incorporating the CountVectorizer into the pipeline and didn't see much difference. Any thoughts/suggestions?